# Creating a Windows installer with automatic download of .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment, installation

I am using Visual Studio Installer project for deploying a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. Is there a way to set up an automatic downloading and installing .NET framework 4.0 Client profile, if necessary, automatically from the Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup installer has an option to both ask and download appropriate the framework from the Internet. It is set in the project.

Click setup project -> properties. On the "properties page" there is a button called "Prerequisites.."

There you have three choices:

- Vendors's website
- Same location as my application
- Download from following location

Choose the appropriate option.

Comment: Yes. Note that the "from same location" can also mean "from my CD"